# Is getting values from randomly defined attributes advisable?

Tags: jquery, html

I am totally shocked when I found that jquery can get value from any randomly defined attribute.

**HTML**

```
<a postid='10' class='delete_post'>Delete</a>
```

**JS**

```
$('body').on('click', '.delete_post', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('postid');
    delete_post(id); //$.post request for deleting post
});
```

I made [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fTUnb/) for testing this.

My question here is => Is it advisable to use such randomly defined attributes to get value?

Generally I get value using below code.

**HTML**

```
<div class='delete_post'>
    <a>Delete</a>
    <input type='hidden' class='id' value='10' />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.delete_post').on('click', 'a', function() {
    var id = $(this).parent().find('.id').val();
    delete_post(id); //$.post request for deleting post
});
```

*(I tested this successfully in chrome, firefox and internet explorer.)*

Comment: Note that this isn't a magical jQuery thing, JS has been able to do this for a very long time - I'm not aware of any browsers that don't support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this will generally work, it is not advisable to use proprietary/user-defined attributes.  These will not validate and there is the possibility of you incorrectly using a real attribute. Your code is also not future-proof in that you may define an attribute that is not used now, but could be used later.

Instead, you should use `data-` attributes / `.data`:

```
<input data-postid=10 class=delete_post>

var postID = $(this).data('postid');
```

Spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes

Comment: Thanks again. I don't know about data- attribute, it helps me to reduce size of my old codes.

Comment: Note that (depending on which version of jQuery you use) an attribute like `data-sample="00123"` will be returned by `.data("sample")` as the number `123` because `.data()` attempts type conversion. If you need the string exactly as it appears in the html use `.attr("data-sample")`.

Comment: Actually although the [jQuery doco](http://api.jquery.com/data/) still says that data conversion is done if possible, testing in jsfiddle I found that with the latest jQuery version data conversion didn't occur for a string with leading zeros.

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 defines it acceptable to use `data-*` attributes.  "any random" probably is less effective than `data-any-random`.